# Proximal Policy Optimization Algorithms paper - definition of "KL" operation?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

In the original paper on Proximal Policy Optimization Algorithms

> https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf

in equation (4) the authors use an operation denoted by `KL[]`. Unfortunately, they never give a definition for it.

My question:

> What does the `KL[]` operation stand for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it's [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence)?

KL divergence is used to compare differences between two probability distribution.